# Getting Myob AccountRight API Access token error

Tags: access-token, myob

I am trying to get access token from MYOB. The POST call i make returns a "400 Bad Request error"
i'm using "axios" to make the POST call
i already got the Access code which i use in the data i'm sending in the POST call

here is my code

```
const config= { headers:{'Content-Type':"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}}
const data={
         client_id:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         client_secret:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         scope:"CompanyFile",
         code: code,
         redirect_uri:"http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A30002Fcallback",
         grant_type : "authorization_code"
         }

axios.post("https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/v1/authorize", data, config)
  .then((res) =>{
                 console.log ("response ...............", res
                 }
        )
  .catch((error) => {
                 console.error("Error here is ........",error)
                    }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios will, by default, attempt to POST your `data` fields as JSON which is not correct.

Instead, you want to url encode them and post the url-encoded string in the HTTP body. See the 'example call' [in the docs](https://developer.myob.com/api/accountright/api-overview/authentication/).

There's a good example of how to url encode w/ axios [here](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-urlencoded/).

I also note that your `redirect_uri` field is already url encoded, so attempting to simply encode it a second time means you'll end up with something like `http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost` which is not correct. Double check your URL encoding against the example call to make sure you're not accidentally encoding certain fields twice.  From memory the access code is already encoded appropriately so you might need to fiddle with decoding it before re-encoding it to get it working.